# For all I care - in Russian

Tags: перевод

"For all I care" generally has the same meaning as "As far as I'm concerned" but is definitely more informal, aggressive even. I have found quite a few sentence fragments expressing "As far as I'm concerned" but none of them seem to have the bite of "For all I care".

- по моему рассуждению
- насколько я могу судить
- по-моему

In very general, you use this in situations when you refer to someone you either don't like or who made you angry, and the part of the sentence after "For all I care" is always referring to something the speaker considers to be a bad choice. Often, the speaker doesn't really mean it but is just being sarcastic.

- "For all I care, you don't have to protect your head at all" (when driving the motor cycle)
- "For all I care, you don't even have to get out of bed today" (thereby missing something very important)
- "For all I care, you can keep paying twice more than everyone else" (when it would be so easy to change that)

How to express the same in Russian?

Comment: That's how one should ask translations questions. All do as @vic does!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I'll try to stick to that format for future questions - and I guess there will be many more as I keep running into situations where I just don't know how to deal with idioms or colloquial speech. Dictionaries are no help at all in such situations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**"По мне, так"** fits your requirements nicely. It's informal and passive-aggressive:

- По мне, так можешь вообще не беречь голову.
- По мне, так можешь вообще не вставать сегодня.
- По мне, так можешь продолжать платить в два раза больше остальных.

You can also use **"Ну и"** or **"Да хоть"**, if it's a generalization. It invokes an imperative, so it's even more aggressive and emotional. On the other hand, it expresses less of a personal opinion:

- Да хоть вообще голову не береги!
- Да хоть вообще сегодня не вставай!
- Ну и продолжай платить в два раза больше остальных!

Comment: Wouldn't "Как по мне, так" be a more stable form?

Comment: @A.S. I thought about this form, too, but some argue that it has a distinctive Southwestern touch: http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=128830

Comment: Indeed - I grew up in (south)-central Ukraine. Never realized it was a form of regionalism. Как по мне, так "по мне так" has a North-eastern touch ;).

Answer (score 6):

Нейтральные выражения : "мне-то что, мне безразлично, меня это не касается, мне нет до этого дела, делай,как знаешь, да, ради бога"

Разговорные: "мне без разницы (параллельно, фиолетово),хоть...и все,что можно придумать с "хоть".

Answer (score 5):

Here are not the literal translations, but maybe you will find these variants useful.

For calm sarcasm, you can use expressions like "Да пожалуйста", "Ну конечно.", "Да на здоровье!", "..., мне не жалко.", "..., мне-то что?".

> For all I care, you don't even have to get out of bed today
>
> Ой, ну конечно, можно ведь и вовсе с постели не вставать.
>
> For all I care, you can keep paying twice more than everyone else
>
> Да пожалуйста, плати и дальше вдвое больше остальных, мне не жалко.

If you want to add more emotions, you can say a sentence with right the opposite meaning, and using some constructions which normally emphasize ask, demand or forbidding, for example, "Боже упаси!", "Ни в коем случае", "Я тебя умоляю" and other ones.

> For all I care, you don't have to protect your head at all
>
> Я тебя умоляю, ни в коем случае не защищай голову!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to find real life translations.

1) Да хоть совсем голову не береги (мозгов то нет) 
It is rude but it is OK between mother and her son.
Here is another word you can use
Сорвиголова! (= Слабоумие + отвага)

2) Даже попу лень c постели поднять
3) Да хоть все деньги отдай

You can also (mis)use proverbs with sarcasm

1) Бережёного Бог бережёт
2) Работа дураков любит / Работа не волк, в лес не убежит
3) Скупой платит дважды

Answer (score -2):

May be "For all I care" means "Всё что меня волнует (интересует)"?

> -I just drive to shop - it's 100m far away!
>
> -I don't care how far you drive, for all I care, you don't have to protect your head at all

.

> -Я просто съездил в магазин - это в 100 метрах!
>
> -Меня не волнует как далеко ты съездил, всё что меня волнует, это то что ты не защитил свою голову (шлемом).